# Time Stamp off/ahead 1 hour in php script

Tags: php, time

I have a time stamp in my form results script, but the time stamp is ahead 1 hour.  Can anyone tell how to adjust the time stamp to be accurate?  or is this just on my pc?

Here is my current code:

```
$Body .= date("Y-m-d H:i A e");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check the timezone on your server.  Most likely, the timezone is set 1 hour differently there than you are expecting.

Comment: I did just that..  The time on my laptop is correct and I'm using a hosting service.  They must be located one hour in the other time zone?  Right?

Comment: Exactly, I have seen this problem many times.  You just need to take in account the difference in where you and your server are located, or adjust the timezone on one of them to be consistent with the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timezone if you have access to the .htaccess file

```
SetEnv TZ "location"
```

location is the timezone you want to set.